# How to schedule a celery task through a django view

Tags: python, django, celery, scheduled-tasks, celery-task

Is there any way to define a date and time in a django view and run a celery task at the defined time?

For example

```
def test(request):
    date = '2020-09-12'
    time = '11:34'
    
    # run the below task at the specified time
    test_celery_test.delay()
    
    ...
```

I want the task to run only once at the specified time and should not repeat

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below

**Lets say this is your task**

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import date
from celery import shared_task,current_task, task
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()

@app.task
def test():

    print ('1')
    todaynow = datetime.now()

    print todaynow
```

**Then you can call like this in your views.py**

```
test.apply_async(eta=datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 30, 11, 35))
```

If you just want to run it once, why do you want to put in your views.py, i would suggest you to look for this same thing in custom management commond or crontab for this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Can you point me on how to accomplish this with crontab from django views?